# Numpy setdiff1d with floating point errors

Tags: numpy

I have two Numpy arrays:

`x = np.array([49.1, 50.0, 30])` and `y = np.array([50.0, 49.10000000000218])`

When I do `np.setdiff1d(x, y)` I get `array([30., 49.1])` but I want it to return `array([30])`.

Is there a way I can set a tolerance?

Comment: This uses `np.unique` and `np.in1d`, which in turn uses `argsort` and `==` test.  `np.isclose` compares floats within a tolerance.  I can imagine combining ideas to get what you want, but `numpy` does not provide that directly.

Comment: @Chris it does, yes. Thank you. I've marked this question as such.

Answer (score 0):

Simple yet effective. You just round before you do the setdiff

```
x = np.array([49.1, 50.0, 30]) 
y = np.array([50.0, 49.10000000000218])
np.setdiff1d(np.round(x,10),np.round(y,10))
```

gives

```
array([30])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'd like to avoid truncating it to any fixed number of digits.